# Get all derivation of HTMLElement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to do an up to date list of all possible html elements.
As I know, all elements is derived from browser's native [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) interface.
My question is how can I query this interface's derived elements, like HTMLParagraphElement, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to do an up to date list of all possible html elements.

Then read the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#index).

While you can loop over all the global functions and test their prototype chains, that will tell you what that particular browser has explicit support for, including elements that are no longer in HTML and not including new ones the browser has not added yet.

```js
const element_creating_functions =
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window).filter(name => {
    try {
      const func = window[name];
      if (typeof func !== "function") {
        return false;
      }
      return window.HTMLElement.isPrototypeOf(func);
    } catch (e) {
      // Some functions are sandboxed on Stacksnippets
      return false;
    }
  }).sort();;
console.log(element_creating_functions);
```